# union of open sets

Tags: general-topology

EDIT : Given a topological space $X$ and $X_i\subseteq X$ for all $X_i$.

Let $U_i$ be an open subset of $X_i$, $i\in I$.
Is it true that $\bigcup_{i\in I} U_i$ is open in $\cup_{i\in I} X_i$?

My opinion is that it is true.

Let $x\in \bigcup_{i\in I} U_i$ then there exits $i^*$ so that $x\in U_i^*$. Let $V$ be a neighbourhood of $x$ in $X_{i^*}$ such that $x\in V \subseteq U_{i^*}$. Take $B= V\cup \bigcup_{i\in I} U_i - U_{i^*}$, then $B$ is a neighbourhood of $x$ in $\cup_{i\in I} X_i$ and $B\subseteq \bigcup_{i\in I} U_i$. So, we deduce $\bigcup_{i\in I} U_i$ is open in $\cup_{i\in I} X_i$.

Comment: Correct.  The trick is the infinite *intersection* need not be open but the union does.  With closed sets it's the exact opposite.  The infinite intersection of closed sets must be closed. But the infinite Union of closed sets doesn't have to be close d

Comment: Are the sets $X_i$ disjoint? What is the topology on $\bigcup_{i\in I}X_i$?

Comment: @bof not necessary

Comment: What if $I=\{1,2\},$ $U_1=X_1=[0,1],$ $X_2=\mathbb R,$ $U_2=\emptyset$? Is that a counterexample? If not, what part of the question don't I understand?

Comment: I agree that it is necessary to precise what topology is put on $\bigcup X_i$ If they are subspaces of a bigger $X$, then the counter-example of bof works.

Comment: Oh, that edit makes it an *entirely* different question.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is false in general. Let $X_a = \{a,-a\}$ for any $a \in \mathbb R, a \geq 0$. The $X_a$ are discrete, hence $U_a = \{a\} \subset X_a$ are open.

But $\bigcup_a U_a = \mathbb R_{\geq 0}$ is not open in $\bigcup_a X_a = \mathbb R$.

Note, that my answer assumes that the $X_i$ live in some topological space $X$ and are endowed with the subset topology. The OP did not mention anything about the construction of a disjoint union (where the truth of the statement would be trivial, as it is the definition of the topology on the disjoint union).

Edit: The OP has clarified his question and my assumptions are verified. So this answer is all fine. Another counterexample (even in the case where the index set is finite) is given in the comments above.

Comment: {x} isn't open in R. It's open in a discreet metric but so is the infinite union.  {a} is only open in $X_a $ as a metric space.  It is not open in the R or in union $X $

Comment: $\{x\}$ is open in $\{x,-x\}$, and thats all what the OP has in his assumption. Actually your comment completely misses the question.

Comment: But you are you certain that the Euclidean topology coincides with the topology of the *set* $\mathbb{R}$, when viewed as a union of the topological spaces $X_a$?

Comment: In my example, the $X_a$ are endowed with the subset topology and so is their union. As long as the OP does not change his wording of the question, this is all fine.

Comment: The OP has clarified his question. The $X_i$ are indeed in some $X$ and are endowed with the subset topology. So the downvoter might want to undo his action.

Comment: But if each $X_a$ is a metric space it is a *different* metric space than $X_b$ and it doesn't make sense to talk of union {x} being open in $X_a$ because union {x} isnt a subset of $X_a$.  We must talk of Union $X$ being the metric space.  Yes {x} *might* (or might not) be open in Union $X$ but if Union {x} *might* (or might not) be open in Union $X$.  If Union $X$ is discrete then Union {x}  **IS** open.

Comment: Oh.  The new edit makes it an **ENTIRELY** different question.